# How to create stripe payment url from server side which will be redirectable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve
here is link but it create payment url in client side. but I want it only from server side so that I can save it temporary in db.

Comment: The code example boxes on that side allow you to switch between different languages and platforms …

Comment: You can create the session server-side, but when you have the session id, you must redirect to checkout on client-side, it's not possible server side https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is you want to store stripe's checkout session link temporarily in DB. The doc shared is the correct one.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(payload);
// get your customer, success and cancel URL, and other details in the payload object.
if (session) console.log(session.url)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Let me know if you were looking for something else.